# editable selectOneMemu appears blank instead of first default string value

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have this editable selectOneMenu which correctly resets/repopulates on its previous selectOneMenu change. but it always show blank instead of the first value - 'Please select/Enter statement'

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="statement" style="width:300px;" value="#{mgBean.statement}" 
editable="true" panelStyle="width:200px;">
>                                   
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select/Enter statement" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems  value="#{mgBean.statementList}" var="stmt" itemLabel="#{stmt.defaultStatement}" itemValue="#{stmt.defaultStatementValue}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `noSelectionOption` attribute

Like this

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select/Enter statement" noSelectionOption="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute `label="Please select/Enter statement"` for the `p:selectOneMenu` tag.